# GCP SecretManager DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error code 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Since I've changed my Internet Provider, I can no longer get access to GCP SecretManager values. It tooks 10 minutes (60000 miliseconds) to get a timeout response. I tried to reduce it with optional argument but it won't work, it's ignored. Am I doing something wrong ?

[image]

It works fine inside the Docker by the way, on the same machine.

My environment is: Windows 10, Using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 version.

Here is the code:

```
  const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager')

  process.env.PROJECT_ID = 'nameOfTheProject'

  module.exports = async (secret, project) => {
    const projectId = project || process.env.PROJECT_ID

    try {
      const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient()

      const [accessResponse] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/secrets/${secret}/versions/latest`
      }, {
        timeout: 3000, // <--- this line is ignored somehow
        maxRetries: 0
      })

      return accessResponse.payload.data.toString('utf8')
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(' service.secrets failed:', error.message)
      return error
    }
  }
```

Comment: It might be a problem with your dependencies. Are your libraries up to date?

Comment: actually I had to flush DNS `ipconfig /flushdns` to make it work. I have no idea why it was the problem ‍♂️

Comment: Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.

Comment: @aspirinemaga I've been having the same problem a *lot* in the last couple months. If it's ISP related, this is a major problem. Is there some sort of DNS poisoning or interception going on? 

Do you mind if I ask whom your ISP is?

Comment: @Randolpho - first try to `ping www.google.com` if it's not responding, then search for a WSL2 internet connectivity issue with your virtual-network adapter. probably that's the case. mine was TMOBILE before, then ORANGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

I'm using Windows 10 with WSL2 (ubuntu 20.04). I had a problem with internet connection within that WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 container. I'm not sure where does this problem came from but I've changed my Internet Provider and the problem occured.

1. I've checked internet connection by `ping www.google.com` (internet doesn't worked)
2. I've flushed DNS `ipconfig /flushdns` inside WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 container.
3. Retried `ping www.google.com` and suddenly it started to work.

Problem came from Network Issues with WSL2 image.